# Javascript redirect by language

Tags: redirect, detect, country

Where can i find a simple javascript redirect code that redirect all the language detected to an english page, except the italian language that has its proper page?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

http://javascript.about.com/library/bllang.htm

```
var langcodes=["fr", "es"];

// Browser Language Redirect script
// copyright 3rd January 2006, Stephen Chapman
// permission to use this Javascript on your web page is granted
// provided that all of the code in this script (with the sole exception
// of the langcodes array entries) is used without any alteration

var langCode = navigator.language || navigator.systemLanguage;
var lang = langCode.toLowerCase(); 
lang = lang.substr(0,2); 
var dest = window.location.href; 
for (i=langcodes.length-1;i >= 0; i--){
  if (lang==langcodes[i]){
    dest = dest.substr(0,dest.lastIndexOf('.')) + '-' + lang.substr(0,2) + dest.substr(dest.lastIndexOf('.')); 
    window.location.replace ?window.location.replace(dest) :window.location=dest;
  }
}
```

Generally, I'd prefer to redirect at the server level (e.g. with mod_rewrite, for Apache):

http://www.giuseppeurso.eu/en/url-redirection-according-to-browser-language-apache-mod_rewrite/

PS:  Here are some additional links, with different alternatives for redirecting based on language:

http://moz.com/community/q/best-practice-to-redirects-based-on-visitors-detected-language

[How to Redirect a Web Page](http://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/)

- HTML redirects
- JavaScript redirects
- Apache redirects
- Nginx redirects
- Lighttpd redirects
- PHP redirects
- Ruby on Rails redirects
- .NET redirects
- Node.js redirects